# Why is this string tokenizer making me cast to string?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I Think I broke this down to the most basic form. If not then I apologize and will try to edit it. Why in my while loop do I need to cast String for the FirstName if I already set the variable to be a String? Am I doing something wrong? I am try to set the FirstName variable to be equal to the first token which is supposed to be the first word of the text file etc.

```
  try
            {
                BufferedReader infileCust =
                        new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\custDat.txt"));
    }
      catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
            {
                System.out.println(fnfe.toString());
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                System.out.println(ioe.toString());
            }
        }

        public static void createCustomerList(BufferedReader infileCust,
                CustomerList custList) throws IOException
    {    
        String  FirstName;
        String  LastName;
        int  CustId;


        //take first line of strings before breaking them up to first last and cust ID
        String StringToBreak = infileCust.readLine();
        //split up the string with string tokenizer
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(StringToBreak);

        while(st.hasMoreElements()){
        FirstName = (String) st.nextElement();
        LastName = (String) st.nextElement();
        CustId = Integer.parseInt((String) st.nextElement());

        }
```

Edit: Apprently I can use nextToken() instead. But how come my variables are being shown as not used? Are they not within the scope of the while loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `nextElement` returns Object. If you call `nextToken`, you would not need to cast.

From the documentation:

> public Object nextElement()
>
> Returns the same value as the nextToken method, except that its declared return value is Object rather than String. **It exists so that this class can implement the Enumeration interface.**

**EDIT** Regarding the variables that are not used: the reason you get the warning is that the variables are assigned, but not printed, saved, or analyzed in some way. If you add a call to, say, `writeln` with first and last name, the warnings would go away.

Comment: Thank you! So nextElement will also use spaces as the delimiter?

Comment: @Sackling In your case, it will use whitespace characters `" \t\n\r\f"`. If you pass a different set of delimeters in the constructor, both nextToken() and nextElement() would use these delimeters.

Answer (score 3):

Because `StringTokenizer.nextElement` returns a `java.lang.Object`. See the docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html You can use `nextToken() : String` instead if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Because [StringTokenizer.nextElement()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextElement%28%29) returns

> The same value as the nextToken method, except that its
>   declared return value is Object rather than String.It exists so that this class can implement the Enumeration interface.